# What's difference between using cakephp console and using IDE to build the application?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am a cakephp newbie and I would like to know what method you guys use to build your cakephp project. The tutorial I read is using cakephp console to bake application but the book I have use IDE to build the application. It seems console is more convenience because it can generate different projects name...Using IDE would require the developer to manually create all the folders...Thanks for the reply...

Comment: Its based on preference, try both and see which you prefer. My preference, would be the console.

Comment: Are there any IDEs that actually build Cake scaffolding for you? In my experience, the time you spend "baking" the app in the console is a tiny fraction of the overall development time, so it shouldn't matter too much.

Comment: If I have a db schema and want a basic CRUD scaffolding, the baking can help speed things up.  It's SO nice when you start from something than from scratch.  However, most of the time I do it by hand.  I'm with handsofaten -- it's such a small part of dev time that I wouldn't worry about picking the "optimal" way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you're not hearing enough of, in the answers so far, is that they're really two different tools with two different purposes. Cake's `bake` command line utility won't really create your application. It will create *scaffolding* for the parts of an application that you define. This is a great starting point, but that's all it is.

You'll use your IDE to flesh out the bits that make your application, well, an application.

Both tools are very, very useful so it's not really an either/or kind of answer. Although I like using the `bake` tool to get started, there really aren't that many folders you have to create if you chose the IDE path. Once you drop in the Cake code base, most of that stuff--even the app-centric bits--are waiting for you to fill them out.

I rarely use `bake` to create views and once I've baked a model or two, I'll often built others from scratch in my text editor. There's no "right" way; just understand what each gives you and use whichever best suits your workflow at a given point in time.

Answer (score 2):

I use both methods, depending on the state of development of the project and/or database.

Often I will copy a controller, model and views and just search & replace the appropriate names.

If I have a lot of database defined, I'll use bake.

As for IDEs, after much pain, frustration and testing I have settled on NetBeans. I did use Komodo for a while when I was forced to work on Windows (Java ate my windows) but now I'm on Ubuntu & Macs Netbeans is powerful, quick and flexible. I still wouldn't touch Eclipse with someone else's, though.

Comment: You ever tried Coda for the Mac?  I love it for my dev work on my macbook.

Comment: I think I did, but it's paid SW isn't it? I try to avoid paying for things. Open Source SW tends to be better developed nowadays, anyway. The most important thing was to have an IDE I could use on any machine.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for something like [ModelBaker](http://www.widgetpress.com/modelbaker).  I haven't personally used it, but from what I can see it's a slick GUI on top of CakePHP.

FWIW, I've been using [JetBrain's PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) and loving it.